GKE Autopilot: probes failing on kube-system pods
I'm running a cluster on GKE Autopilot and I'm experiencing a lot of probes failing on kube-system pods. For example:
Liveness probe failed: Get "https://10.95.128.210:10250/livez" on a metrics-server pod
Startup probe failed: Get "http://127.0.0.1:9879/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9879: connect: connection refused on a anted-* pod.
I am having trouble finding out if this is something I should be worried and about and if I should solve it, how to solve it. I've had almost 10k occurrences in the last 30 days.
If you need any more information feel free to ask, I'm very new to this subject so I don't know what information you will need.
I tried going through the logs of some of the failing pods, but by the time I figured out which pod is causing the issue it seems to be terminated already.
